# Message displayed "Downloading Update..." wont go away

Tags: linqpad

I have a licensed copy, currently on 5.3.1 and noticed in the top right of my window, I see this.  Not sure how long this has been there.  What can I check?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 5.3.1 sounds quite old as we're now on 5.36.03. It might be worth doing a once-off manual update as there could be a bug with the old version and it cannot download the new version correctly. Hopefully from then on auto update will work for you.
Also if you're behind a proxy, ensure your proxy settings are correct.

Comment: yep, that did it.  just downloaded the newest release and installed that.  picked up my license as well.